# Why does Perl not garbage collect memory when a large array is deallocated?

Tags: perl, memory-management

I know that Perl uses reference count based garbage collection.
When a variable goes out of scope, the reference count is decremented and if REFcount goes to 0, the memory is de-allocated.
But when I trace a small example which is shown below, I couldn't able to find the de-allocation happening.

```
print "start..";
```

[image: memory usage at start state]

```
sub func
{
    my $length = 8*1024*1024;
    my $array = [1..$length];
```

[image: memory usage after allocation]

```
}

func();

print "done..";
```

[image: memory usage during garbage collection stage]

In the example, when the program starts, Perl.exe occupies ~ 3 MB physical memory.
After allocation during the func() call, Perl.exe occupies ~ 370 MB memory.
But after the func() call , the allocated memory should be garbage collected. why is it not done?

Looking forward for your replies.

Comment: If you have to reallocate huge amount of memory in perl, fork it, allocate memory, process data and exit child.

Answer (score 19):

According to the question "[How can I free an array or hash so my program shrinks?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq3.html#How-can-I-free-an-array-or-hash-so-my-program-shrinks-)" in [perlfaq3](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq3.html):

> You usually can't. Memory allocated to lexicals (i.e. my() variables)
>   cannot be reclaimed or reused even if they go out of scope. It is
>   reserved in case the variables come back into scope. Memory allocated
>   to global variables can be reused (within your program) by using
>   undef() and/or delete().
>
> On most operating systems, memory allocated to a program can never be
>   returned to the system. That's why long-running programs sometimes re-
>   exec themselves. Some operating systems (notably, systems that use
>   mmap(2) for allocating large chunks of memory) can reclaim memory that
>   is no longer used, but on such systems, perl must be configured and
>   compiled to use the OS's malloc, not perl's.
>
> In general, memory allocation and de-allocation isn't something you
>   can or should be worrying about much in Perl.
>
> See also [How can I make my Perl program take less memory?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq3.html#How-can-I-make-my-Perl-program-take-less-memory)

Comment: Wow. Lexical variables never free memory even if they are out of scope? I knew that applied to package variables unless you use `undef`. I guess this isn't too bad since the largest blocks of data are usually done with references.

Comment: Perl prefers performance over small memory footprint. You can always `undef @a;` on lexicals too. It will free the body and string buffers of scalars, and it will free the underlying array of arrays.

Comment: If the `func()` is executed again, there is no considerable amount of memory increase. So I think, it is clear that Perl flags the memory as 'not used' if REFcount = 0, but never returns the memory to OS. This 'not used' flagged memory is used in future for any other allocations.

Answer (score 13):

Perl may have marked the memory as freed, but it doesn't necessarily mean that it has been [freed back to the OS](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=333464). Your Perl program may reuse that memory. Try running `func` again. You shouldn't see an increase in the amount of memory used.

You may want to set the environment variable [`PERL_DESTRUCT_LEVEL`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhacktips.html#PERL_DESTRUCT_LEVEL) and see if that makes any difference, but I doubt it.

[Garbage collection](http://www.jwz.org/doc/gc.html) is not one of Perl's greatest strengths.

Comment: I did exactly same (before seeing your answer :) ) and i could see that there is no increase in memory. So, I have just returned here to let the people know about this. But Happy to see that @DavidW has already pointed this out.